# Why are the angle brackets being escaped in my link?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am generating a thumbnail of an image and I want to use the thumbnail as a link.  I have the following code

```
$img = $thumbnail->show($options, $tag_options);
echo $this->Html->image("thumbs/".$img);
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("thumbs/".$img),array('controller'=>'images', 'action'=>'view', $image['Image']['id']));
```

The first echo statement works correctly and displays the image.  the second one displays a link that looks like this

```
<img src="/app/webroot/img/thumbs/fa741043357d4bf1ca39a58edf351d2a.JPG" alt="" />
```

now the link works correctly in the sense that it takes to the view page for that image, but it is not displaying the image as I would expect it to.  when I view page source the link looks like this:

```
<a href="/index.php/images/view/9">&lt;img src=&quot;/app/webroot/img/thumbs/fa741043357d4bf1ca39a58edf351d2a.JPG&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; /&gt;</a>
```

I noticed that the angle brackets on the img tag are escaped.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For security reasons, HTML entities like that are escaped in the `title` by default when using the `link`  method.

You have two options:

the `image` method can take a `url` as a parameter.

```
echo $this->Html->image('thumbs/' . $img, array('url'=> 
                                               array('controller'=>'images', 
                                                     'action'=>'view', 
                                                      $image['Image']['id'])
                                               )
                        );
```

or you can use the `link` method and turn off escaping, in the 3rd parameter (where you can set `title`, `id`, `class` etc)

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("thumbs/".$img),
                        array('controller'=>'images', 
                              'action'=>'view', $image['Image']['id']),
                        array('escape'=>false, 'class'=>'example') // here
                      );
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was missing something simple.  I can't try this until I get home. I'll accept it then.

Comment: +1 for the 'url' option that I had never noticed before and that really means less code to write